# Google Motion chart in JSP

Tags: jsp, google-visualization

I follow the google motion chart link however Im using jsp to generate data and pass that data to loader jsp (jquery ajax request). Below is my code. Please help me to fix this.

### display jsp : (This page calls ajax request for data from database)

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Motion Chart</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsapi.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadMotionChart(){
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "./chart-loaders/motion-chart-loader.jsp",
        dataType: "json",
        data:"DB="+'myDB',
        async: false
        }).responseText;
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);
        var options = {
        title: 'Motion Chart', is3D : true
        };

        var motionchart  = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('motionChart'));
        motionchart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container">
    <div id="motionBox">                
    <input type="button" value="Load Chart" onclick="loadMotionChart()" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="motionChartContainer">
    <div id="motionChart" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;" />
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### loader jsp: (This page is the loader page in which I try to create json string and pass back to display jsp)

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*, java.util.*, java.text.*" %>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject,net.sf.json.JSONArray"%>
<%      
    Connection conn;
    .
    .
    .
    String data = "[[\"Item\",\"Date\",\"Amt1\",\"Amt2\"],";
    try
    {
        ResultSet rs=null;
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        monthOffset = "2013-01-01";
        monthLimit = "2013-02-28";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select dbo.doGetMotionChartData('" + monthOffset + "','"+monthLimit+"')"); 

        while (rs.next())
        {
            resultData = rs.getString(1);
        }


    itemTokens = new StringTokenizer(resultData, "#");
        itemSize = itemTokens.countTokens();

    // at this point I get whole data as one string("resultData") then I use string tokenizer to split and make data in required format.
    for (int i = 0; i < itemSize; i++){
            tmpitemToken = itemTokens.nextToken("#");
            collectionTokens = new StringTokenizer(tmpitemToken, "|");
            collectionSize = collectionTokens.countTokens();
            for (int j = 0; j < collectionSize; j++){
                tmpCollectionToken = collectionTokens.nextToken("|");
                collectionSplit = tmpCollectionToken.split(",");
                dateSplit = collectionSplit[1].split("-");

        data += "['" + collectionSplit[0] + "'," + "new Date("+dateSplit[2]+","+dateSplit[1]+","+dateSplit[0]+")" + "," + collectionSplit[2] + "," + collectionSplit[3] + "]" + "," ; 
        }
        }
     /*
    final Data = [["Item","Date","Amt1","Amt2"],['Item1',new Date(2013,01,01),618699.88,603694.00],['Item2',new Date(2013,01,01),2650229.78,3124956.02],['Item1',new Date(2013,02,01),179667.66,354520.00],['Item2',new Date(2013,02,01),229715.02,1208445.76]]
    */
     out.print(data);
        out.flush();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi when I've used this I've always used single quotes for text and nothing round dates

data.addRows([
 ['PXPP-F-N-D',new Date (2012,0,01),85336.35,2245.69,1012.70]]);

All best
Barry

PS

I always use this example from google as a start point https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart

```
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Fruit');
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
    data.addRows([
      ['Apples',  new Date (1988,0,1), 1000, 300, 'East'],
      ['Oranges', new Date (1988,0,1), 1150, 200, 'West'],
      ['Bananas', new Date (1988,0,1), 300,  250, 'West'],
      ['Apples',  new Date (1989,6,1), 1200, 400, 'East'],
      ['Oranges', new Date (1989,6,1), 750,  150, 'West'],
      ['Bananas', new Date (1989,6,1), 788,  617, 'West']
    ]);
```

Comment: Hi Barry I have edited my question. please check again now. thanks

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Is it possible to see what the final html would look like that gets sent to the api? Sorry I'm not a jsp kind of guy. Just hoped it was as simple as matching the format stipulated by Google. Your ["Item","Date","Amt1","Amt2"] was at odds with the way google set out and the way I've used it. I'm an Oracle plsql person that just thought he could help.

Comment: is3D : true I don't think is a valid option for a motion chart. Neither is the title, has this come from a pie chart example?

Comment: does this site help? https://sites.google.com/site/youvisualize/motion-chart---json-from-url

Comment: yes Barry, you are right. Initially I was working with pie chart and once done(success) with it I moved to motion chart. I don't think is3D is a problem. Regrading error, my page not throwing any error since output page code is in javascript. Anyways your above link is a good one. Let me work on that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For Motion chart edit this line and in place of `corechart` use `motionchart`

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

and in place of `PieChart` add `MotionChart`

```
var chart= new google.visualization.PieChart(
    document.getElementById('chart-div')
);
```